# How long does JUnit keep references to tests?

Tags: java, heap-memory

If the junit or Regression tests run on Jenkins, after each tests class deleted all variable on heap (befor it starts new test class)? or are deleted at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit keeps a reference to each test as long as it runs. That means you get **one** (1) instance of your test case class per test **method** and these instances live until JUnit prints the test results.

If you run out of memory, you need to set the fields of the test instance to `null` in an `@After` method.